# Legend item resolution issues in ArcGIS Javascript app

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

When I create a pdf map using my JavaScript API app, the legend items have messed up resolutions when there are more than a few swatches in the legend layers:

On the left: image of print with poor resolution on swatches, on the right: image of .mxd template
 [image: image 1].

The only way to correct this is seems to be to make the legend one column at the service level:

On the left: image of print with good resolution on swatches, on the right: image of .mxd template
 [image: image 2].

The only parameter in the 'Web Map as JSON' string that seems relevant is the DPI, but changing that has no effect. I have also messed with the Legend properties dialog box in the corresponding mxd to no avail. The bug seems to occur when the legend adjusts the number of columns. This issue is more than a year old for me, with no luck googling the heck out of it... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a silly bug with a silly workaround. The workaround will actually work even though it sounds so incredible.

Here's the steps on getting it working:

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40538

I know it says 10.1, but 10.2 is affected too. When choosing paper size, go large... plotter large. Make sure you're the user that runs the arcgis service as it says.

Comment: I just upgraded to 10.3.1 and I had to do this again, I'm surprised they don't address this issue - what an ugly glitch -  thanks, again

Comment: We might be upgrading to 10.3 soon too, so at least now we know what to expect, thanks! But agreed.. it is a shame they haven't addressed it, but not surprising...